# Get origin for newly created user on firebase auth trigger

Tags: firebase, authentication, triggers

Is there a way to know if a newly created user was done so using the client or admin SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the auth trigger isn't origin specific. It doesn't care how a new user account gets created... it doesn't get called/triggered until the creation occurs.

Not to go too far off topic from your question, or turn this into a fully-fledged conversation, but what are you trying to accomplish that you want to detect what created the account? I feel like there's probably a different way to handle the scenario you're facing.

Comment: Basically I want to disable user creation via the client SDKs and only allow it via the admin SDK without disabling the email/password auth provider. I am doing custom validations with a register endpoint in my api.

Comment: @rhyek Unfortunately the best option will probably be to create a white-list user table in the database. Right before the admin SDK creates a user, first add that new user's email to the white-list, and then create the user. Then set up the auth trigger cloud function for whenever a user gets created to check if new user's email is in white-list, and if not, delete the newly-created unauthorized user right away... and if it *is* on the white-list, then don't delete the new user and instead remove the entry from the white-list table.

Comment: You should lock down the white-list table's security rules so that no one has read/write access - the admin SDK bypasses security rules and always has read/write access to everything.